# Cannot change data type of SAP Hana column

Tags: hana

I try to change data type of column of Hana's table and get an error: "

**feature not supported: cannot modify column type from bigint to integer**

". Alter table statement:

> ALTER TABLE "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME" ALTER ("C_BIGINT" INTEGER );

Table DDL:

> CREATE ROW TABLE "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME" ("C_BIGINT" BIGINT);

Seems like I have all required grants but get error for any data type I'm trying to change to.

Comment: Create a new table with columns you need and insert the converted data. This is much faster although you would need the double space for a short moment. Don't forget constraints, index, ... on the new table.

Comment: @Christian4145  I cannot recreate table or use another one. I need to change current table. Anyway I'm confused why cannot apply so simple DDL operation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change data type to a smaller size, like from BigInt to Int
I followed a different approach to implement your requirement

I added a new column with INT data type

Update new column values from BIGINT column.

At this UPDATE command, for values larger than INT data type will cause error
If you don't have any such values, you can continue with next step

Drop old column

Rename new column using the old column name

That's all

```
CREATE ROW TABLE "TABLE_NAME" ("C_BIGINT" BIGINT);

ALTER TABLE "TABLE_NAME" ADD ("C_INT" INT);

UPDATE "TABLE_NAME" SET C_INT = C_BIGINT

ALTER TABLE "TABLE_NAME" DROP ("C_BIGINT");

RENAME COLUMN "TABLE_NAME"."C_INT" TO "C_BIGINT";
```